# Virtualbox Resolution: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Host - OS X El Capitan Guest

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I managed to install OS X on Virtualbox and it works fine for my purpose,  which is basically trying to be cool. Anyway, I wanted to optimize the resolution for OSX.

This worked fine

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N
```

But that only sets the resolution of the OSX to some default resolutions (n=0,1,2,3,4,5 corresponding to 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900, ect)

Is there a way to set the Mac OS guest to 1920 - 1080 for virtualbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/478901/change-macos-x-guest-screen-resolution-for-virtualbox), it worked for me with OS X Lion.

I'm not sure it will work for El Capitan

Comment: Seems like the com.apple.boot.plist and the com.chameleon.Boot.plist files are not in El Capitan anymore.